# Strange behavior with c++11 thread in gcc 4.8.1

Tags: linux, multithreading, gcc, c++11

Here's my code.

```
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
//#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

void f() {}

int main() {
    //struct timespec t;
    //clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &t);
    thread(f).join();
    return 0;
}
```

I have tried to compile this program in the following ways:

```
1. g++ a.cc -o a -std=c++11 -pthread
2. g++ a.cc -o a -std=c++11 -lpthread
3. g++ -pthread a.cc -o a -std=c++11
4. g++ a.cc -c -std=c++11 && g++ a.o -o a -lpthread
5. g++ a.cc -c -std=c++11 -pthread && g++ a.o -o a -pthread
```

All of them can output the executable "a". However, none of them seem to link the library "libpthread.so":

```
./a
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::system_error'
  what():  Enable multithreading to use std::thread: Operation not permitted
Aborted

ldd ./a
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff997fe000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f350f7b5000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f350f59f000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f350f1d6000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f350eed2000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f350fad4000)
```

But, the following way works perfectly:

1. uncomment all the three lines in the above code(must do this, or the same error appears);
2. using "g++ a.cc -std=c++11 -o a -lrt".

I'm using ubuntu 13.10. Any reason for this?

Comment: If you compile with `g++-4.8  -std=c++11 -Wall a.cc -lpthread -o a` (using GCC 4.8.2 on Debian/Sid) your program works ok (and without the explicit `-lpthread` I am getting the same error as you get).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This would seem to be a known Ubuntu related bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gcc-defaults/+bug/1228201).

You can (as noted on the linked page) work around it by passing `-Wl,--no-as-needed` on the command line;

```
 > g++ a.cc -pthread -std=c++11
 > ./a.out
 terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::system_error'
   what():  Enable multithreading to use std::thread: Operation not permitted
 >

 > g++ a.cc -pthread -std=c++11 -Wl,--no-as-needed
 > ./a.out
 >
```